# Vagrant ruby path issues with cmder

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, path, ruby, cmder

I recently installed [cmder](http://cmder.net/), a terminal that is more customizable / visually easier than windows command prompt.

When I run a command like `vagrant ssh` in cmder, I get this error:

> Exec error: exec: "ruby": executable file not found in %PATH%

If I use gitbash I get the same problem.

I didn't have any %path% problems before I started using cmder.

Comment: all I could find on this issue was here https://teamtreehouse.com/community/nothing-happens-when-i-type-vagrant-ssh

Comment: You said "I use gitbash I get the same problem", so I don't think it's related to cmder.

Comment: I meant, git bash had no problems running vagrant commands until I used cmder, and then gitbash also had problems. So cmder is somehow? changing my vagrant dependencies for ruby.

Comment: Do you run gitbash *inside* cmder? If you don't, cmder is not an issue.

Comment: I't possible that your anti-virus software is deleting C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\mingw64\bin\ruby.exe (or equivalent).